# MapView suddenly stopped working on React Native Expo app, android only

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I have an expo project that has been working just fine for more than 2 months now, been testing it pretty much every day. Since today, 15th August 2022, the MapView component from react-native-maps module has stopped working on android, while on iOS it works just as usual. It just shows a blank map with the little google logo at the bottom. I have also noticed that the showcased snack at the [official expo-map-view documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/) has the exact same problem when ran ("Try out this example on Snack") , and again, on android only.

I am also pretty sure it is not an api key related issue as the documentation says

> "No additional configuration is necessary to use react-native-maps in Expo Go. However, once you want to deploy your standalone app you should follow instructions below."

after we run `expo install react-native-maps`

Does anyone have a solution for this? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: Found a temporary solution. Downgrading Expo go app from version 2.25.1 to 2.24.3 and Expo SDK from 46 to 45 seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command before you starting the app:

```
adb logcat | grep "Google Maps Android API"
```

and then start it.